# R interpretations of multivariate time series in csv format

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I have the data set "aid_given_per_person_2007_us.csv" from https://www.gapminder.org/data/.

Using the following commands i am trying to make R interpret this as a time series data set.

```
AidPerCapita<-read.table("aid_given_per_person_2007_usa.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

When I run head(AidPerCapita) I get:

> country.1960.1961.1962.1963.1964.1965.1966.1967.1968.1969.1970.1971.1972.1973.1974.1975.1976.1977.1978.1979.1980.1981.1982.1983.1984.1985.1986.1987.1988.1989.1990.1991.1992.1993.1994.1995.1996.1997.1998.1999.2000.2001.2002.2003.2004.2005.2006.2007
> 1                          Australia,51.7,60.1,61.2,75.6,75.3,85.3,89.9,104,98.1,107,114,102,116,90.8,108,130,83.8,88.3,115,114,107,92,124,109,107,122,119,86,122,102,91.1,96.8,96.7,96,100,105,86.4,87.7,92.6,90.5,95.9,90.3,94.1,93.1,93.4,98.6,119,127

How can I make R understand that country is not one of the variables and that instead every observation should have a year attached to it, similar to:

Australia

1. Year  - Aid Given Per Person
2. 1960         -  100
3. 1961          - 109
4. 1962         -  111
5. 1963         -  110

Austria

1. Year  -  Aid Given Per Person
2. 1960     -      156
3. 1961     -      179
4. 1962      -     171
5. 1963       -    203

etc.

I have tried:

```
AidPerCapita2<-as.xts(AidPerCapita)
```

But it I get an error

> Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is "long" format instead of wide format. You can convert the table using the tidyverse package tidyR. Here's some example code on what you can do:

```
library(readr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# You can load the data and convert it to long format
data <- read_csv("aid_given_per_person_2007_us.csv") %>% 
  gather(Year, Aid_Given, -country, convert = T)

# You can filter only countries you want
oceania <- data %>% 
  dplyr::filter(country %in% c("Australia", "New Zealand"))

# You can plot the developement of all countries
ggplot(data, aes(x = Year, y = Aid_Given, color = country)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1, na.rm = T)

# Or of only those you have previously selected
ggplot(oceania, aes(x = Year, y = Aid_Given, color = country)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1, na.rm = T)
```